# Why vector cause Segmentation fault Error?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I wanted to make Random number from Openssl.

So. I made program :

```
#include "openssl/rand.h"
struct randomData
{
     char str[32];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<randomData> vecStr;
    randomData rd;
    vecStr.emplace_back(rd);

    RAND_bytes((unsigned char *)vecStr[i].str, sizeof(vecStr[i].str));

    std::string ss = to_hex(vecStr[i].str, sizeof(vecStr[i].str));
    std::cout << "Random Nonce Hex Data : " << ss << " // Key Length : " << ss.length()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
// [out put]
// Random Nonce Hex Data : f0f5e38e596fdb2f7cef79d3706fcbf111decaa844154295b89b90eb65925a53 // Key Length : 64
```

But I don't want to make struct. Just use **vector**.
So, I tried.

```
std::vector<char> str;
str.reserve(33);
RAND_bytes((unsigned char *)&str, sizeof(str));
std::string ss = to_hex((char*)&str, sizeof(str));
std::cout << "Random Nonce Hex Data : " << ss << " // Key Length : " << ss.length() << std::endl;

// [ output ]
// Random Nonce Hex Data : f1935de540b5a75bcaa9eab4b173abcb6a840bf83c4181ee // Key Length : 48
// Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You can see the error log. 
I searched a difference "reserve" with "resize". But those function caused same error.

Why this happen??

Comment: What's `RAND_bytes`?

Comment: If you do this type conversion `(unsigned char *)`, you do something wrong.

Comment: `&str` should be `&str[0]` or `str.data()`. You want the address of the first element/data not the address of the vector itself.

Comment: @rveerd str.data() not caused segment error but the ouput is wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it should be `resize`, not `reserve`.

Second, use `.data()` instead of a cast to pointer type.

Third, it is `str.size()`, not `sizeof(str)`.

```
std::vector<char> str(33);
RAND_bytes(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(str.data()), str.size());
std::string ss = to_hex(str.data(), str.size());
```